# Google chrome and cache

Tags: spring, google-chrome, spring-security

all,

I am building a service using Spring 3.0 and i am using spring security for authorization/authentication. I have correctly setup the Apache/Tomcat ajp setup to use SSL and send appropriate cache headers for all static resources (1 week) which Firefox seems to interpret correctly (i can tell from firebug that it doesn't fetch these resources each time). On the other hand, Google chrome will only fetch the static resources (.css, .js) from cache for the login page. For all the rest of the pages/requests it sends a GET to the server and then the server replys with a 304 Not Modified response. If i disable SSL caching works normally but only for the same jsessionid that Spring security uses. I have checked the browsers cache and i actually saw that for plain HTTP resources are getting cached but are bound to a specific jsessionid i.e.

```
http://localhost/myservice/resources/jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js;jsessionid=3B15E163E138CCE8839306FF5A924D87
```

I am confused...can anyone help?

Thanks